# Error in MySQL syntax from Pycharm. Pycharm signals syntax error and doesn't run queries that can be run in MySQL Workbench

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to run simple queries that can be run on MySQL Workbench but they do not run from Pycharm. Pycharm alerts and stops the program due to a SQL syntax error. (I am accessing the same database from both Pycharm and MySQL Workbench).

In the first image the simple querie runs.

then I add an ORDER BY line and it prompts me a SLQ syntax error
The last image shows that the querie can be run on MySQL

[image: RUNS THIS ONE LINE QUERIE]

[image: DOESN'T RUN WHEN I ADD "ORDER BY"]

[image: THE SAME QUERIE RUNS IN MySQL Workbench]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to put an space at the end of the first string

DOESN'T WORK:
query = ("SELECT SSN, ModelN FROM Tech_expert"+
"ORDER BY SSN")
WORKS:

query = ("SELECT SSN, ModelN FROM Tech_expert "+
"ORDER BY SSN")